# Hollow 3D shape with perforated or mesh exterior in OpenSCAD?

Tags: openscad

How can I create a perforated or mesh 3D shape using OpenSCAD?  e.g.  a hollow cylinder/sphere with a pattern of tiny holes on the outside?

```
cylinder(40,10,10);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your basically going to code it.  Open Scad doesn't have anything like textures.  so lets say you want to make a hollow golf ball, complete with dimple pattern.

some rough pseudo code  they actual math of where to put the dimple would be a lot more complicated, I'm just do a ring of dimples around the x/y plan.

```
difference(){
      sphere(10);
      sphere (9);   Hollow it out
      for(i= 0 to 10)
      {
         x = 10 * sin(i)
         y = 10 * cos (i)
         z = 0
         translate([x,y,z]) sphere (1)
      }
}
```